# Cloudfront not caching despite Cache-Control

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Cloudfront distribution that points to a server that resizes images from an S3 bucket. The server returns a `Cache-Control` header with `public, max-age=31104000`, but I keep getting 
`miss from Cloudfront` so the images are not cached in Cloudfront.

To test, I set up another Cloudfront distribution that points directly to the S3 bucket, and that indeed caches the images with `hit from Cloudfront`.

I compared the request and response headers, and the only difference is that the miss has a `Last-Modified` header response, which is missing from the good request. However, I'm not sure that's the problem.

Do you have any idea of what is happening? Here are the headers:

```
Good Response:
Age:10
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31104000
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Sat, 05 Sep 2015 16:15:51 GMT
ETag:"51dbe11a5fa320c4495221b69df1d860"
Server:AmazonS3
Via:1.1 b7bc8b4c398aa9f5a08980055c497334.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:4KE-cAoFrTmcjkRW3goZAImvyQE5i1Vl4KZyrWL8HyCk6GcJZ9N7Kw==
X-Cache:Hit from cloudfront

Bad Response:
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31104000
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Sat, 05 Sep 2015 16:16:42 GMT
ETag:"51dbe11a5fa320c4495221b69df1d860"
Last-Modified:Sat, 05 Sep 2015 16:07:41 GMT
Server:nginx/1.6.2
Via:1.1 45578d14a69df96accaab0d1aba82a5a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:FGMRwDI0vOJQ7aPj83s-RGTO0fg_Zesu7FLo7Ia5vwCxcTZI97ri5A==
X-Cache:Miss from cloudfront

Good Request:
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0    .8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,da;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:assets.runemadsen.com
If-Modified-Since:Sat, 05 Sep 2015 16:07:41 GMT
If-None-Match:"51dbe11a5fa320c4495221b69df1d860"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (    KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36

Bad Request:
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0    .8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,da;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:images.runemadsen.com
If-Modified-Since:Sat, 05 Sep 2015 16:07:41 GMT
If-None-Match:"51dbe11a5fa320c4495221b69df1d860"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (    KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any idea why there's no `Content-Length:` or `Content-Transfer-Encoding:` header in either response?  It seems like one or the other would be mandatory, in the presence of `Connection: keep-alive`.  If your resizer is sending neither header, CloudFront may be assuming the response is got was of unknown validity.  The docs [claim](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#ResponseCustomDroppedTCPConnections) the object is cached in that case, but that seems sketchy.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that if you repeat the same request, over and over, CloudFront repeatedly fetches if from the origin and never serves it from cache?  Is your origin server returning a `Date:` header?  Capturing (and mentioning) what your origin server actually returns may be useful here.  Also verifying... you didn't configure CloudFront to forward all request headers to the origin server, did you?  Doing that [disables caching](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. Here's the final update: The reason was that an older response without the `Cache-Control` was cached in Cloudfront, which somehow made cloudfront continously reload the image from the origin. I'm not sure exactly how a cached response can trigger constant "miss", but that's what happened. I invalidated the route, and Cloudfront started cahing the images.